# Is there a way to do the following query with joins instead of a sub query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, subquery, materialized-view, greatest-n-per-group

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I want to eliminate having to use the following sub query so I can create an indexed view.

The only thing similar to my problem is the greatest-n-per-group queries but I want all the values, instead of only the last measured factor ones.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
      eu.[Name],
      pp.[MonthDay] --date type,
      pp.[Value] * 
            (SELECT TOP 1 [Factor] FROM [em].[CO] co 
            WHERE co.[EUID] = eu.[Name] 
            AND co.[MonthDay] <= pp.MonthDay 
            ORDER BY [MonthDay] DESC) AS [CO]
            --multiply by the last measured factor
            --I also want to remove the sub query
FROM em.[PPGenData] pp
JOIN em.[PPEUID] eu
ON eu.ID = pp.ID
```

Comment: Why do you think this query will benefit from an indexed view? That's a serious question. A lot of people think indexed views are magic.

Comment: I put a condensed version of my view here, there are actually 7 sub queries in the same format with a different table and factor. I felt like it would get me the data faster.

Comment: Show the whole query, not a dumbed-down version, because the form of those other subqueries might lead to a better solution. Show sample data, desired results, and the execution plan you're currently getting (post the XML somewhere, don't show us a picture). Refactoring your query to support some construct you "feel like" might work faster does not seem productive to me. YMMV.

Comment: `OVER` clause is not allowed in indexed views either, so solutions with `ROW_NUMBER` would not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it, but like Aaron said it would be more useful to have the context around the rewrite.  You can probably write this more simply using `WHERE EXISTS()` rather than `TOP 1` or `ROW_NUMBER()`, but without knowing your schema I'd rather not speculate.

```
SELECT
    EU.Name,
    PP.MonthDay,
    PP.Value * Y.Factor AS CO
FROM
    em.PPGenData AS PP
    INNER JOIN em.PPEUID AS EU ON PP.ID = EU.ID
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            ID, Factor
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                PP2.ID, CO.Factor, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PP2.ID ORDER BY CO.MonthDay DESC) AS Seq
            FROM
                em.PPGenData AS PP2
                INNER JOIN em.PPEUID AS EU2 ON PP2.ID = EU2.ID
                INNER JOIN em.CO AS CO ON EU2.Name = CO.EUID
            WHERE
                CO.MonthDay < PP.MonthDay
            ) AS X
        WHERE
            Seq = 1
        ) AS Y ON PP.ID = Y.ID
```

Note that subquery X needs to be wrapped in another subquery since a windowed function cannot be used in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

this just trying to figure out your syntax:

```
    SELECT eu.[Name],
           pp.[MonthDay] --date type,
           pp.[Value] *  ( SELECT TOP 1 [Factor] 
                             FROM [em].[CO] co 
                            WHERE co.[EUID] = eu.[Name] 
                              AND co.[MonthDay] <= pp.MonthDay 
                            ORDER BY [MonthDay] DESC 
                         ) AS [CO] 
    FROM em.[PPGenData] pp
    JOIN em.[PPEUID] eu
             ON eu.ID = pp.ID
```

I think this will work:

```
select *  
(     
    SELECT eu.[Name],
           pp.[MonthDay] --date type,
           pp.[Value] * co.[Factor] as [ValueTimesFactor],
           row_number over(partition by co.[EUID] order by co.[MonthDay] DESC) as rn
      FROM em.[PPGenData] pp
      JOIN em.[PPEUID] eu
               ON eu.ID = pp.ID
      JOIN em.[CO] co 
               on co.[EUID] = eu.[Name] 
              AND co.[MonthDay] <= pp.MonthDay 
)     tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

or

```
SELECT eu.[Name], pp.[MonthDay], pp.[Value],
       pp.[Value] * max(co.[Factor]) as [ValueTimesFactor],
  FROM em.[PPGenData] pp
  JOIN em.[PPEUID] eu
           ON eu.ID = pp.ID
  JOIN em.[CO] co 
           on co.[EUID] = eu.[Name] 
          AND co.[MonthDay] <= pp.MonthDay  
 GROUP BY eu.[Name], pp.[MonthDay], pp.[Value]
```